# Using Matlab Google-Earth Toolbox to plot Latitude and Longitude

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, google-earth

I am trying to plot some waypoints using the [Google-Earth toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12954). The documentation for it is pretty poor, so I figured this would be a good Stack Overflow question.

I have a matrix, `wypts` that has pairs of latitude and longitude coordinates in decimal format (If anyone is wondering this over the State College Airport (SCE) in Pennsylvania).

```
wypts =
   40.8489  -77.8492
   40.8922  -77.8492
   40.9355  -77.8492
   40.9788  -77.8492
   41.0221  -77.8492
   41.0654  -77.8492
   41.1087  -77.8492
   41.1154  -77.8492
```

The following does not work instead of plotting points in Pennsylvania, it plots nothing in the off the south pole:

```
output = ge_plot(wypts(:,1),wypts(:,2))
ge_output('wypts.kml',output)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your latitudes and longitudes mixed up. The help documentation for `ge_plot` says that the first input should be longitude, and the second input should be latitude. Try this:

```
output = ge_plot(wypts(:,2),wypts(:,1));
ge_output('wypts.kml',output);
```

Comment: And goes directly back to my point about their documentation, when is longitude ever first? :p

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Yeah, that's confusing, especially when you can type `40.85 -77.85` into the search bar for Google Maps and get the point you want. Not sure why they would reverse that in the toolbox.

Comment: Try thinking about latitude / longitude in a 2D XY projection.

We normally state "X" then "Y" when plotting etc. Now a change in Longitude is a change in "X". A change in Latitude is a change in "Y".

I've seen this problem in numerous places. Always look at the documentation. Never assume!