# Google Earth Toolbox could not load in MatLab

Tags: matlab, google-earth

I'm trying to install GOOGLEEARTH TOOL on matlab,
the download website is
https://code.google.com/archive/p/googleearthtoolbox/downloads

But it appears that

```
  >>googleearth -docinstall
  Adding 'demo' folder to the path...Done.
  Warning: Non-fatal error during version file update. 
  >In googleearth at 29 
  Adopting user-customized styles for documentation files...Done

  Click on the MATLAB Start button->Desktop Tools->View Source Files...
 and click Refresh Start Button.
```

My matlab version is R2012b, and I can't find the start button ,or desktop tools, or 'view source files'.

Does anyone know? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older versions of MATLAB, the "Refresh Start Button" menu option forced MATLAB to parse a new [`info.xml`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html#bsflmds) file (containing meta-data about a toolbox) and add the relevant components to MATLAB's start menu. This option no longer exists, as MATLAB should *automatically* parse an `info.xml` file.

From the MATLAB documentation:

> MATLAB parses the `info.xml` file and displays your documentation when you add the folder that contains info.xml to the path. **If you created an `info.xml` file in a folder already on the path, remove the folder from the path. Then add the folder again, so that MATLAB parses the file**. Make sure that the folder you are adding is not your current folder.

The Google Earth toolbox looks like it creates an [`info.xml`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html#bsflmds) file on the fly to better integrate documentation, demos, etc. with MATLAB. It creates this `info.xml` file *after* adding the toolbox directory to the path.

To simulate the effects of "Refresh Start Button" on your version of MATLAB, you will likely need to remove and *re-add* the toolbox to your path. At this time, MATLAB should parse the `info.xml` file  properly.

```
rmpath('/path/to/googleearth')      %// Remove the previous path
addpath('/path/to/googleearch')     %// Add the path back
```

Comment: @AlisaW What "hints" are you talking about? You will still get the same messages you have posted above; however, it ensures that the toolbox is installed completely.

Comment: @AlisaW See my previous comment. Those words are built into the installer and *won't* change. Removing and then adding the path has the same effect and you can safely ignore those lines

Comment: So you mean this GOOGLEEARTH tool has been installed successfully?

Comment: @AlisaW Yes. You should be able to use it and access the documentation and demos successfully now. Also you should see it within the start menu

Comment: I did like what you said. However, when I tried to play these order [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867238/using-matlab-google-earth-toolbox-to-plot-latitude-and-longitude), nothing appeared, there is no image.

Comment: I didn't receive any error and MATLAB didn't show any picture. But I opened the wypts.kml document produced by MATLAB in Google Earth, and it shows a line. So maybe this tool doesn't produce picture, but only creat a KML file which can be displayed within GOOGLE Earth. Thanks so much.