# Using Matlab Google-Earth Toolbox to plot multiple lines at a time

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, google-earth

I am trying to plot some trajectories using [the Google-Earth toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12954).

I have many matrixs, each of them  has pairs of latitude and longitude coordinates in decimal format.
For example,

```
wypts1 =
    40.8489  -77.8492
    40.8922  -77.8492
    40.9355  -77.8492
    40.9788  -77.8492
wypts2 = 
    41.0221  -77.8492
    41.0654  -77.8492
    41.1087  -77.8492
    41.1154  -77.8492
```

(My data is more complex compared to this)
.And I know using following code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867238/using-matlab-google-earth-toolbox-to-plot-latitude-and-longitude)

```
 output = ge_plot(wypts(:,2),wypts(:,1));
 ge_output('wypts.kml',output);
```

it can creat kml file, which can be displayed by Google-Earth.

But I want to display different kml files at the same time,and with different colors is better, so that I can compare these trajectories. Is this realizable in Google Earth? Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the google earth can open multiple kml files at the same time. Just choose them all.